# Error install Azure Functions with npm package

Tags: azure, npm, azure-functions

I'm trying to install the package *azure-functions-core-tools* with npm but I get the following error

[image: https://i.imgur.com/g87Qv6N.png]

I'm using this command to run the install

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools
```

I don't understand why is trying to use a proxy by default. I haven't set any proxy.

I've tried the following codes to remove the proxy tunnelling:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-prox

npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

After running that code I get a different error

[image]

I also reinstalled NodeJS and deactivated all VPNs and Antivirus.

The idea is to install the CLI to authenticate to Visual Studio Code to start creating Azure Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a system variable named HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY. Even set to null forces npm to use it (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy)  Go to Environmental Variables panel and delete it from there. That should do the trick